# Magmi Image Import - some files being imported, but not others

Tags: image, magento, import, magmi

I am struggling with a magmi import.  I have a test csv file in /var/import with 29 records in it.  All images are held in media/import, and have been given the permission 644.

I get the following error when running the import for these files :

```
Image attributes processor v1.0.25 - fb-096-gemini-basin-mixer.jpg cannot be found in images path
Image attributes processor v1.0.25 - fb-096-gemini-basin-mixer.jpg cannot be found in images path
Image attributes processor v1.0.25 - fb-096-gemini-basin-mixer.jpg cannot be found in images path
Image attributes processor v1.0.25 - fb-95-shino-designer-radiator.jpg cannot be found in images path
Image attributes processor v1.0.25 - fb-95-shino-designer-radiator.jpg cannot be found in images path
Image attributes processor v1.0.25 - fb-95-shino-designer-radiator.jpg cannot be found in images path
....
```

And so on for 6 files out of the 30 records.  So some images in the path (e.g. the other 24 files used in the import) are being found, but not others.

Any assistance would be gratefully received.

Justin.

Comment: Is your filesystem case sensitive ? , are they any whitespaces around the values in the csv ?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Dweeves. All filenames are in lower case. However, I have just checked the csv file, and there is a single trailing space in the .jpg filenames of those that are not loading correctly. Thankyou - I would never have thought to look for that. :-).

Comment: the latest git version is now "whitespace agnostic", but official 0.7.18 has this little glitch

Comment: just my luck :-), thanks !

Comment: just chmod magmi/state & magmi/conf dirs to have write access for web server user. i guess zip delivery from github did set all to 644 or less.

Comment: excellent, all working now, thanks !